# Cmake: Telling find_package to look for the 32 bit library (instead of the 64bit lib)

Tags: boost, cmake

So far I haven't found this in the cmake documentation, but I need to link a program against a 32bit boost library on my mac and I couldn't figure out how to tell cmake to look for the 32bit version using find_package..

Answer (score 0):

Are the libraries available in different Prefixes? Then defining the BOOST_ROOT variable to point to the specific prefix might help.

Otherwise, you are of course free to overwrite the found libraries after the CMake configuration, e.g. by using ccmake.